# subtraction of matrix using operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, operators, dynamic-arrays

I am working on operator overloading in c++, in this program, I have to get matrix size and values from the user at run time  and perform operator overloading (subtraction) on two objects and assign it two third object and display matrix in third object, the  code Is below

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
class matrix{
    int **matrixList;
    int row;
    int col;
    public:
    explicit matrix(){};
    matrix(int**,int,int);
    matrix operator-(matrix);
    void getValues();
    void displayMatrix();
};
matrix::matrix(int** matrixList,int row,int col){
    this->matrixList=matrixList;
    this->row=row;
    this->col=col;
}
void matrix::getValues(){
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        cout<<"\n enter value in row "<<i+1<<"\n";
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
            cin>>matrixList[i][j];
    }
}
matrix matrix::operator-(matrix obj){
    matrix tmpObj(matrixList,row,col);
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            tmpObj.matrixList[i][j]=this->matrixList[i][j]-obj.matrixList[i][j];
        }       
    }
    return tmpObj;
}
void matrix::displayMatrix(){
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col; j++){
            cout<<"  "<<matrixList[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){

    int **matrixPtr;
    cout<<"enter no of rows : ";
    int row;
    cin>>row;
    cout<<"enter no of columns : ";
    int col;
    cin>>col;

    matrixPtr = new int *[row];
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        matrixPtr[i] = new int[col];
    }
    
    matrix obj1(matrixPtr,row,col);
    obj1.getValues();
    matrix obj2(matrixPtr,row,col);
    obj2.getValues();
    matrix obj3(matrixPtr,row,col);
    obj3=obj1-obj2;
    obj3.displayMatrix();

    for(int j=0;j<row;j++){
        delete[] matrixPtr[j];
        }
        delete matrixPtr;
}
```

if I give the size of row and column as 4 in the above code it gives output like this

```
  0   0
  0   0
```

Comment: Did you debug your code step-wise?

Comment: Please, have a look at [The rule of three/five/zero - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The missing copy constructor makes my stomach hurting. (Especially, because you pass your object by value e.g. in the `matrix::operator-()`.) - If you had used `std::vector` instead of all these `new[]`s, it could be that you had bought correct copying by default (for free).

Comment: On the second glance, I realized something even more horrible: All your objects of `matrix` share the same storage for values. (You always pass the pointer to the one and only `matrixPtr` in `main()`.) A - A = [0] makes sense then... To fix this, I would strongly recommend that `matrix` manages the storage of its values on its own and internally.